# Automatically extend pattern in FL Studio

Tags: fl-studio

I have a midi file. My goal is to remove piano track and add metronome sound to midi and export it in order to play along on a piano. I have already figured out how to remove piano track and add metronome. I drew the metronome beat pattern in piano roll tab and now I need to extend it to the end of the track. Since the track is very long I don't want to do it manually with copy and paste.

How can I repeat the pattern to the end of the track automatically?

Comment: Can you use pictures?? I don't get what you want to extend?? The pattern? Why dont you just keep repeating it??

Comment: Yes, I want to repeat pattern. As I said in my question, I cannot keep repeating it manually since the track is very long and every change in pattern will waste much of my precious time. Adding screenshots is a nice advise, will do when I get back home.

Answer (score 1):

There are two very fast ways to repeat your patterns.
1 - You can duplicate the patterns on the playlist by pressing **Ctrl+b**
2 - You can draw the patterns continously by using the brush icon.